# Error while adding tags to a worpdress post based on its id using python

Tags: python, wordpress, request, tags, wordpress-rest-api

**Hello , I'm trying to add tags to a wordpress post based on its ID using python , but I keep getting this error :**

````
```Error adding tags to post 540: {"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): tags","data":{"status":400,"params":{"tags":"tags[0] is not of type integer."},"details":{"tags":{"code":"rest_invalid_type","message":"tags[0] is not of type integer.","data":{"param":"tags[0]"}}}}}```
````

Hereis the code that I'm running , **I provided within the code the correct Api key and the wordpress url this is just for testing purposes** :

```
import requests



site_url = "https://set-services.shop"

# Replace YOUR_WORDPRESS_API_KEY with your WordPress API key
api_key = "T70A Bb2B HyF9 xS4L tzka R782"
# Set the number of posts to retrieve
posts_per_page = 100

# Set the page number to retrieve
page = 1

# Set the base URL for the WordPress API
api_url = f"{site_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"

# Set the parameters for the API request
params = {
    "per_page": 100
}

# Set the headers for the API request
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " +api_key
}

POST_ID = 540
#
# # Set the endpoint for updating the post
endpoint = site_url + f"/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{POST_ID}"
#
# # Set the headers for the HTTP request

#
# # Set the list of tag names that you want to add to the post
tag_names = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
#
# # Set the payload for the HTTP request
# # In this case, we want to add the tags to the post
payload = {
     "tags": tag_names
 }
#
# # Send the HTTP request to update the post
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, json=payload)
#
# # If the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
#     # Print a success message
     print(f"Successfully added tags to post {POST_ID}")

else:
#     # Print an error message
     print(f"Error adding tags to post {POST_ID}: {response.text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the Tag IDs, not the name. And the tags have to be comma-separated string, not an array. (The API reference is a bit misleading here)

Comment: thanks for your reply , I did fix the problem with WP REST API , all what was needed is to download a package of it from github to fix the raising issues of editing .